# Code snippet causing asset precompile to fail on heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, precompile

I'm trying to deploy a rails/react app to Heroku, but my  rake assets:precompile kept failing due to an unexpected token (>).  I've narrowed it down to this quick fix to ensure react router scrolls to the top of the page on route changes (the app deploys fine when I comment it out, but fails precompile when I put it back in).

Can someone help me to understand why this code would cause the precompile failure?  I assume it has to do with the arrow operator, but I don't really understand how it works to be honest.  In the meantime, I'll be learning what that does so I can try to recreate it, but I'd really like to understand why this doesn't work for future reference.  Thanks!

Here's the code snippet that's causing the problems:

```
browserHistory.listen(location => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (location.action === 'POP') {
      return;
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
});
```

Here's the top of the stack trace:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 11668, col: 33, pos: 318450)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:11870)
remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:12089)
remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:20898)
remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:21035)
remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:21123)
remote:        at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3572:29660)
remote:        at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20160604-553-1fg4s41js:3573:143)
```

Answer (score 1):

It was the arrow function syntax.  Rewriting the snippet long-form resolved the issue.  I'm not sure why it doesn't like the arrow function syntax, but this made it happy.

```
browserHistory.listen(function(location) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (location.action === 'POP') {
      return;
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
});
```